# Dependencies in Python project

Tags: python

I am currently working on a Python project, and I want the user to automatically have access to the dependencies that I used. Do they have to download (e.g. `pip install`) them manually? If so, is there an easy way to make them download the necessary packages easily?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a [virtual environment](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-virtual-environment/), see the link on how to, Then could use `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, to store your env dependencies to a file and then your user can simply use `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install them in one go

See [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files) for more details

Comment: I think the command puts all installed packages in my computer into requirements. How can I make it specific to my project?

Comment: you need to use virtual environment. i will add the details

Comment: If I wanna publish my project on GitHub, do I have to upload my virtualenv? Or, do we just normally upload the requirements.txt?

Comment: Just upload requirement.txt

Answer (score 0):

1. `virtualenv` is What you need. You install packages your project needed when developing it. After coding, you can run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to save all packages to requirements.txt. `pip install -r requirements.txt` will install all packages automatically.

   2. further, `Docker` is more better for releasing projects to PC.